# How to catch an error in Haskell and ignore it?

Tags: haskell, error-handling, ghc

I have a function that takes an integer, checks if it's equal to **1** if yes returns **1** else **error "SomeError"**.

```
func i = if i == 1 then 1  else error "SomeError"
```

Now i have another function that calls this function and check the result of it

```
check = let z = (func 2) in 
  case (Just z) of
    Nothing -> do Something
    _ -> do Something else
```

I tried `z = (func 1)` and `z = (func 2)` for both z in `case (Just z) of`
it goes to do Something else so what i understand here is error is not **Nothing**

So what is **error "SomeError"**? how can I know that `(Just z)` is an error using `case (Just z) of`

Comment: Can you say what it is you want to do at a higher level?  Do you 1. want a pure function, such as `func` that can return successfully or an error (doable with different types)?  or 2. want to catch an exception in a pure function (not possible)? or 3. Something else?

As it stands, your question exposes a few misunderstands but conceals your overall goal.

Comment: `error` has type `String -> a`, and has nothing to do with the `Maybe` type constructor. This means instead of `func :: Int -> Int`, you probably want `func :: Int -> Maybe Int`, with `func i = if i == 1 then Just 1 else Nothing`.

Comment: You cannot catch errors made with `error "..."` or `undefined`. This is by design – Haskell provides things like `Maybe` and `Either`, as well as `IOException`, to remove the need for that.

Answer (score 2):

Try to avoid error where possible. Change `func` to

```
func :: Int -> Maybe Int
func 1 = Just 1
func _ = Nothing
```

then you can write `check` as you have (or similarly, anyway):

```
check = case func 2 of
          Just z -> ...  -- z matches whatever is wrapped by Just
          Nothing -> ...
```